# How to recognize on PHP that Facebook App was uninstalled

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am developing the application by Facebook PHP SDK.
If a user uninstalls this application from the Facebook page, I'm going to delete related data from my app. Is there any way of recognizing uninstallation of an application by PHP?

Comment: you don't have access to the user's information anymore, that's the detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs on authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):

> **App Deauthorization**
>
> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the
>   app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a
>   Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we
>   will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter,
>   signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just
>   removed your app. You will not receive an user access token in this
>   request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically
>   expired.

Comment: Because my environment is Japanese, this text("Deauthorize Callback URL") had been replaced with another text. I have understood your opinion by using English environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can access updates about your app using [Facebook Realtime Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). These are webhooks - urls you provide on your server - which facebook `POST`s information to when various actions happen, such as the user uninstalling your app.