# Checking Who Has Uninstalled Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, oauth

We are looking at different ways to check who has uninstalled your Facebook app weeks after the uninstallation has occurred. We know about [Facebook's post call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391375/how-to-recognize-on-php-that-facebook-app-was-uninstalled) at the time of the uninstallation, but how can you check if the user has uninstalled the app at a later stage than the time of the event? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any reliable way other than what you already mentioned. Why not just store that a user has uninstalled your app?

If you have the "deprecate offline access" migration enabled, then access tokens are granted to your app for 60 days and you can check if the token is still valid. ([Details here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)).

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments there are other reasons an access token can become invalid without the user uninstalling the app. The obvious is token expiration and less obvious, password changes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. We do normally capture that, however, one of our apps missed this for a little bit and we were looking at ways to get access to the missed calls.

Comment: I don't believe there's an API endpoint you can hit to explicitly ask whether a user has uninstalled an app.

Comment: Bugger :). We thought this may be the case, but were trying to find if anyone discovered a work around. It would be good to have this for the sake of the end-user as well as the developer.

Comment: While the answer is right as far as I know (and I've marked it up) note that there are other reasons a token may be invalid other than the user has installed the app. If they change their password, tokens are invalidated, even though the app may be sill authorized.

Comment: @Robbie Absolutely correct. I should have added that in the answer.